How to fix Google CLS issue - "A late network request adjusted the page layout"
We are experiencing a CLS issue which causes a Cumulative Layout Shift of 0.285 on our website. So how to fix the Google CLS issue of the following image shows. The jquery.min.js and jquery-migrate.min.js is automatical added by the WordPress plugin. Is there anyone can help me to solve this issue? Thank you.


The significant shift is caused by the big top ad. Initially, there is no space for it, but then suddenly, the space is allocated.
If I block adsbygoogle.js then the shift does not happen.
You can fix it by preallocating the space needed for that add in the HTML or initial CSS.
